# Sitecore 8.2 Workflow Stuck in Final Step

Tags: sitecore, workflow, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8.2, sitecore-workflow

I'm working on implementing a three step workflow for my company's Sitecore 8.2 installation.

Originally I had the final step set up to not have any action or command because we want to manually publish. But, manually publishing does not seem to remove the final workflow state.
[Screenshot of the items workflow state after manually publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuytV.png)

Then when I edit the item, it doesn't move back to the draft state. It's my understanding that when you publish an item that made it to the final workflow state version 1 is created, and editing that item should create a new version and restart the workflow. Is this correct?

After realizing that manually publishing does nothing, I tried setting up a command and action on the final workflow step:
[Screenshot of final workflow step command & action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1V5h.png)
But this does nothing. Is it possible to set up a workflow action to publish? Or is the out of box auto-publish action the only option?

Why are the items getting stuck in this final step and how do I fix this?

**Edit:** The workflow was getting stuck because I am an admin. When using the roles I set up for Content Author and Approver, I was finally able to get the item to start version 2. I would still like to know if it's possible to set up a command and action to publish? Or is this not necessary if we want to manually publish anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think i know the issue. I had similar issue while setting up my sitecore workflow and i solved it with some changes in the security settings.

I wrote a blog just now about how to setup Sitecore Workflow. Here is the link for that:

https://tectraveleat.wordpress.com/2018/06/01/sitecore-workflow-setup-v8u2-v9-0-1/

In your case, since you have already setup everything. You might want to take a look at the "Assign security permissions to the roles" section of the blog.
Also, it is necessary to give the roles/users permissions to the datasource. From what i understand, you have setup everything properly, except a minor security permission at the workflow level.

Let me know if this helps. If not, can you share your workflow setup and permissions for the roles? I can take a look at it and see it i can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow sample workflow of sitecore. Workflow publish state is final state. It can not move to draft. This process of workflow like this: Draft -> Approved -> Published. Workflow done at here.

If you wanna create version or make page to draft you have to edit it. If you still wanna your page published -> draft, you can custom pipeline of command in workflow. But this solution have many risks, I asked Sitecore support before and they answer it just their logic and you can custom if you want.